# Find an entity where its ManyToMany relationship contains two specific entities

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data, jpql

I have the following entity structure with a many to many relationship:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener::class)
class EntityA {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long?,
            
    ...
            
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "EntityAEntityB",
        joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "entityA_id")],
        inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "entityB_id")]
    )
    var entityBs: MutableList<EntityB> = mutableListOf()

    ...

}

@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener::class)
class EntityB {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long?,

    ...

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "entityBs")
    var entityAs: MutableList<EntityA> = mutableListOf()

    ...

}
```

I'm struggeling to understand what the best way write a where clause which selects that two specific elements of EntityB are included in EntityA.

My first intuition was to just use the `in` clause like this

```
select entityB
from EntityB entityB
where :entityA1 in entityB.entityAs
  and :entityA2 in entityB.entityAs
```

This resulted in a sql syntax error because it is translated to `entityA0_.id in (.))`

The following is my current solution, but I have a feeling that this should work in a better and more readable (probably more performant) way.

```
select entityB
from EntityB entityB
where :entityA1 in (select innerEntityA from EntityA innerEntityA join innerEntityA.entityBs innerEntityB where entityB = innerEntityB)
  and :entityA2 in (select innerEntityA from EntityA innerEntityA join innerEntityA.entityBs innerEntityB where entityB = innerEntityB))
```

Can you think of a better query than my working example for what I want to achieve?

(Please ignore some minor syntax errors in my examples.. these are just examples which I edited from my exiting code)

Comment: You might try 'MEMBER OF': "Select b from EntityB b where :a1 MEMBER OF b.entityAs AND :a2 MEMBER OF b.entityAs". Alternatively, switching things around might give a better performing SQL query (not sure though): "Select b from EntityB b where exists (select a from b.entityAs a IN (:a1, :a2))".

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Both of your suggestions helped me alot. Had to adapt the second query by exchanging the "exists (SUBQUERY)" keyword with "2 >= (select count()...)". Thank you very much!